# Guardar datos de un JCheckBox en SQL Server?

Tags: java, sql-server

Tengo los siguentes JCheckBox:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y neecesito recoger os datos de cada uno de ellos para insertaros en la tabla con un "si" si lo selecionan, y "null" si no lo seleccionaron, alguien tiene idea como puedo hacer eso????

Aca dejo el código que uso para guardar el resto que son jtextfield

```
JButton btnIngresar = new JButton("Ingresar");
btnIngresar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        try {
            Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Prueba2ºIF;user=sa;password=123456789;");

            if (MisMetodos.buscarCi(ci.getText())) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El empleado a ingresar ya existe");
            } else {
                String sentenciaSQL = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Empleado]"+
                                      "([Ci],[Nombre],[Apellido],[Apellido],[Direccion],[Email],[Celular],[Licencia],[Arma],[Fulltime],[MejorArteMarciial],[NumeroServicio])VALUES"
                                      + "("+"'"+ci.getText()+"','"+nombre.getText()+"','"+apellido.getText()+"',"+direccion.getText()+",'"+mail.getText()+"','"+ cel.getText()")";

                Statement statement = conexion.createStatement();
                statement.executeUpdate(sentenciaSQL);
            }

            conexion.close();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Libro Ingresado");
        } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Puedes añadir el código que hayas probado? De esta manera podremos ayudarte mejor, y tu pregunta será mejor recibida

Comment: Todavía no he probado códigos por que no he encontrado como hacerlo, lo que pero paso como guardo el resto.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias utilizar el metodo isChecked() que tienen los checkBox para verificar si estan marcados o no , esto te devolvería un boolean, entonces haces un if para si es true ,

```
String infoCheckBox = null;
if(checkBox1.isChecked()){ 
   infoCheckBox = "si";
}
```

Y esta variable se la puedes pasar a tu consulta insert para que quede reflejado en la base de datos que "SI" esta marcado el checkbox a la hora de la insercion.

Aunque yo personalmente te recomendaria que simplemente almacenases un boolean en esa variable,y le pasases ese boolean a la base de datos.Espero que te sirva de algo.